# Problem updating or installing new packages

Tags: apt, updates, initramfs

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm trying to install lightdm as gdm is not working.

**Edit (problem with gdm)**:

The problem with gdm is that when I boot the computer, it get stuck at the ubuntu splash screen.

I deleted the "quite splash" configuration from the grub configuration, and now the system goes into tty console.

If I go into the terminal while Ubuntu is stuck on the logo screen, I see the next message:

`A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)`

Also, I have noticed that some services fail to start at boot, such as Network Manager, WPA supplicant, LBM....

My first approach was to install Lightdm

The problem is that whenever I try to install or update any package, I get this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: 
initramfs-tools

Error:GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.36" (uid = 0 pid = 7955 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto" label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.PackageKit" member)="StateHasChanged" error n.

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I looked for solutions but none of them worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: Please be detailed on which solutions you already tried so repetitions can be avoided.

Comment: I tried removing some space in the disk, and running commands such as sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: I edited the post with the initial problem

Comment: Did you restart the `dbus` service? `sudo systemctl restart dbus`

Comment: Service is up, but when I try to restart: `Failed to restart dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop)`

Comment: The title and question does not make clear exactly which problem you need help with. The `start job running for Hold ` issue has been asked (and answered) many times; are you asking about that? If not, which previous thread are you following? If that's the problem that you are asking about, then be specific about what you did: How much space did you free up? Is tht the complete list of packages that you removed? However, it seems like all this is barely relevant to your immediate problem, which seems to be apt (initramfs-tools). Is that the problem you are asking about? So confusing.

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Did you try rebuilding the ramdisk(initramfs)?

Comment: @user535733 Basically my problem is that all the solutions I saw need to download packages and install them. So I would like to solve the initramfs-tools problem so I can use the apt functionality again.